# AWS ECS xray sidecar "write: connection refused"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-xray

I am trying to start an ECS task with 2 containers, app and xray as sidecar. Following several blog posts and examples, I am still facing the error that no XRAY segments are visible in the Xray AWS console.
And obviously the error is, that the application cannot connect to the xray-sidecar to send the xray segments.
The line in the app container log showing this:
**[Error] write udp 127.0.0.1:35963->127.0.0.1:2000: write: connection refused**

Overall ECS service/task setup:

- *ecsTaskRole* has the policy AWSXRayDaemonWriteAccess attached
- network mode in task definition is *bridge* => according to instructions, then I have to set env variable *AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS* in my app container, as well as link it to xray-daemon container
- using dynamic port mapping: 2000/tcp and 2000/udp in the xray container, and 9000/tcp in the app

The taskdefinition you'll find below. I also tried to avoid dynamic port mapping, but the error was the same.

What do I miss , so that I can see my xray segments withing the AWS XRay console ?

- is the IAM *AWSXRayDaemonWriteAccess* for the ecsTaskRole not sufficient ?!?!
- app container config missing something, so that it can connect to **xray-daemon container** via the env property **AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS** ?!?! I already tried to set it to different values, like *0.0.0.0:2000* , *127.0.0.1:2000* .... which one is the way to go ?

---

=== app container log ===

```
2020-06-06 14:36:36rate: 0.050000
2020-06-06 14:36:361591446996579912116 [Trace] SamplingStrategy decided: true
2020-06-06 14:36:361591446996579934272 [Trace] Closing segment named jukebox-front
2020-06-06 14:36:361591446996579987354 [Error] write udp 127.0.0.1:35963->127.0.0.1:2000: write: connection refused
2020-06-06 14:36:362020/06/06 12:36:36 ping requested, reponding with HTTP 200
2020-06-06 14:36:362020/06/06 12:36:36 ping requested, reponding with HTTP 200
2020-06-06 14:36:361591446996564675990 [Trace] Beginning segment named jukebox-front
2020-06-06 14:36:361591446996564705526 [Trace] Determining ShouldTrace decision for:
```

=== xray container log ===

```
2020-06-06 13:27:212020-06-06T11:27:21Z [Info] HTTP Proxy server using X-Ray Endpoint : https://xray.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
2020-06-06 13:27:212020-06-06T11:27:21Z [Info] Starting proxy http server on 0.0.0.0:2000
2020-06-06 13:27:012020-06-06T11:27:01Z [Info] Using region: eu-central-1
2020-06-06 13:26:412020-06-06T11:26:41Z [Info] Using buffer memory limit of 19 MB
2020-06-06 13:26:412020-06-06T11:26:41Z [Info] 304 segment buffers allocated
2020-06-06 13:26:412020-06-06T11:26:41Z [Info] Initializing AWS X-Ray daemon 3.2.0
```

The ECS task definition looks like:

```
{
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/ecsTaskRole",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {      
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "secretOptions": null,
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/td-jukebox",
          "awslogs-region": "eu-central-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 0,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 9000
        }
      ],
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS",
          "value": "0.0.0.0:2000"
        },
        {
          "name": "PORT",
          "value": "9000"
        }
      ],
      "memoryReservation": 128,
      "image": "<<app-image>>:latest",
      "essential": true,
      "links": [
        "xray-daemon"
      ],
      "name": "jukebox"
    },
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "environmentFiles": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "secretOptions": null,
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/td-jukebox",
          "awslogs-region": "eu-central-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 0,
          "protocol": "udp",
          "containerPort": 2000
        },
        {
          "hostPort": 0,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 2000
        }
      ],
      "command": [
        "\"-t\"",
        "\"0.0.0.0:2000\""
      ],
      "cpu": 32,
      "memoryReservation": 256,
      "image": "amazon/aws-xray-daemon",
      "essential": true,
      "name": "xray-daemon"
    }
  ],
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2"
  ],
  "family": "td-jukebox",
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "EC2"
  ],
  "networkMode": "bridge"
 }
```

Any help to resolve the **write: connection refused** error highly appreciated ;)

===========

## **Update**

I edited the task definition and added additional parameters for the XRay daemon to startup, to increase the verbosity in log output (as suggested by @shariqmaws ):

```
-l,dev,-f,/var/log/xray.log,-o,-n,eu-central-1
```

After redeploying the service and exec'ing into the xray-daemon container, the /var/log/xray.log contains:

```
tail -f /var/log/xray.log
2020-06-06T16:33:07Z [Debug] ARN of the AWS resource running the daemon:
2020-06-06T16:33:07Z [Debug] No Metadata set for telemetry records
2020-06-06T16:33:07Z [Debug] Using Endpoint: https://xray.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
2020-06-06T16:33:07Z [Debug] Telemetry initiated
2020-06-06T16:33:07Z [Info] HTTP Proxy server using X-Ray Endpoint : https://xray.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
2020-06-06T16:33:07Z [Debug] Using Endpoint: https://xray.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
2020-06-06T16:33:07Z [Debug] Batch size: 50
2020-06-06T16:33:07Z [Info] Starting proxy http server on 0.0.0.0:2000
2020-06-06T16:34:07Z [Debug] Skipped telemetry data as no segments found
2020-06-06T16:35:07Z [Debug] Skipped telemetry data as no segments found
2020-06-06T16:36:07Z [Debug] Skipped telemetry data as no segments found
2020-06-06T16:37:07Z [Debug] Skipped telemetry data as no segments found
2020-06-06T16:38:07Z [Debug] Skipped telemetry data as no segments found
2020-06-06T16:39:07Z [Debug] Skipped telemetry data as no segments found
2020-06-06T16:40:07Z [Debug] Skipped telemetry data as no segments found
```

hmmmm, unfortunately not really an error happening here... This leads me to the assumption that maybe the app-container does something weird to connect to the xray-daemon ?!?!

Within the app-container, the XRAY related env variables look good:

```
 env | grep XRAY
XRAY_DAEMON_PORT_2000_UDP_PROTO=udp
XRAY_DAEMON_PORT_2000_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.7:2000
XRAY_DAEMON_PORT_2000_UDP_ADDR=172.17.0.7
XRAY_DAEMON_ENV_AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI=/v2/credentials/0e9e6ca8-c6d1-4f72-975e-aa3d99fdb64e
XRAY_DAEMON_ENV_ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4=http://169.254.170.2/v4/8a6cd6e9-bda7-4579-8415-471a435d14b4
XRAY_DAEMON_PORT_2000_UDP_PORT=2000
AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS=xray-daemon:2000
XRAY_DAEMON_ENV_ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI=http://169.254.170.2/v3/8a6cd6e9-bda7-4579-8415-471a435d14b4
XRAY_DAEMON_PORT_2000_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.7
XRAY_DAEMON_PORT_2000_UDP=udp://172.17.0.7:2000
XRAY_DAEMON_PORT_2000_TCP_PORT=2000
XRAY_DAEMON_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.7:2000
XRAY_DAEMON_ENV_AWS_EXECUTION_ENV=AWS_ECS_EC2
XRAY_DAEMON_NAME=/ecs-td-jukebox-13-jukebox-d0ddb483ebf899aee801/xray-daemon
XRAY_DAEMON_PORT_2000_TCP_PROTO=tcp
```

The IP 172.17.0.7 is the correct one, matching the IP of the xray-daemon container.

===========

## **Update 2**

I was testing a plain `echo` command within the app-container to send data via UDP 2000 to the xray-daemon, by executing
`echo "test data" > /dev/udp/172.17.0.7/2000`
...and it worked...at least it was successfull to send it, but of course the format of the xray-segment was wrong.
Based on that I received in the xray-daemon logfile:

```
2020-06-06T18:53:45Z [Warn] Missing header or segment: test data
2020-06-06T18:54:07Z [Debug] Send 1 telemetry record(s)
2020-06-06T18:55:07Z [Debug] Send 1 telemetry record(s)
```

Althoug it says `Send 1 telemetry record`, in the AWSXray console nothing appears...still no data. And after waiting a couple of minutes in the xray-daemon logfile appears:

```
2020-06-06T19:03:07Z [Debug] Failed to send telemetry 1 record(s). Re-queue records. SerializationError: failed to unmarshal response error
        status code: 400, request id:
caused by: UnmarshalError: failed decoding error message
        00000000  3c 68 74 6d 6c 3e 0d 0a  3c 68 65 61 64 3e 3c 74  |<html>..<head><t|
00000010  69 74 6c 65 3e 34 30 30  20 42 61 64 20 52 65 71  |itle>400 Bad Req|
00000020  75 65 73 74 3c 2f 74 69  74 6c 65 3e 3c 2f 68 65  |uest</title></he|
00000030  61 64 3e 0d 0a 3c 62 6f  64 79 20 62 67 63 6f 6c  |ad>..<body bgcol|
00000040  6f 72 3d 22 77 68 69 74  65 22 3e 0d 0a 3c 63 65  |or="white">..<ce|
00000050  6e 74 65 72 3e 3c 68 31  3e 34 30 30 20 42 61 64  |nter><h1>400 Bad|
00000060  20 52 65 71 75 65 73 74  3c 2f 68 31 3e 3c 2f 63  | Request</h1></c|
00000070  65 6e 74 65 72 3e 0d 0a  3c 2f 62 6f 64 79 3e 0d  |enter>..</body>.|
00000080  0a 3c 2f 68 74 6d 6c 3e  0d 0a                    |.</html>..|

caused by: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
2020-06-06T19:04:07Z [Debug] Send 2 telemetry record(s)
2020-06-06T19:05:07Z [Debug] Send 1 telemetry record(s)
2020-06-06T19:06:07Z [Debug] Send 1 telemetry record(s)
2020-06-06T19:07:07Z [Debug] Send 1 telemetry record(s)
```

I guess, this is based on the string I sent, which if of course not a valid xray segment.

===========

## **Update 3**

Excerpt of the go code, to verify the instrumentalisation

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-go/xray"
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
)

...

func getXRAYAppName() string {
    appName := os.Getenv("XRAY_APP_NAME")
    if appName != "" {
        return appName
    }
    return "front"
}


type pingHandler struct{}

func (h *pingHandler) ServeHTTP(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    log.Println("ping requested, responding with HTTP 200")
    writer.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
}

func main() {
    xraySegmentNamer := xray.NewFixedSegmentNamer(getXRAYAppName())
    http.Handle("/ping", xray.Handler(xraySegmentNamer, &pingHandler{}))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+getServerPort(), nil))
}
```

Any more hints to troubleshoot why my app cannot connect to the xray sidecar ?!?!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try changing:

```
  "environment": [
    {
      "name": "AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS",
      "value": "0.0.0.0:2000"
    },
```

#### to

```
  "environment": [
    {
      "name": "AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS",
      "value": "xray-daemon:2000"
    },
```

Comment: Hi shariqmaws, many thanks for your quick reply.
I changed the task definition to "xray-daemon:2000" and redeployed the service.....but the error remains the same.....

Comment: We need to check the sray daemon logs, maybe it is unable to start for some reason: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-daemon.html#xray-daemon-logging

Comment: Hi @shariqmaws,
I update the question according to your suggestion....means:
task-def has been updated and log verbosity and log-file setting has been added. After redeploying the service, the logfile doesn't show any error (see content above, in the *Update* section).
Any further hints/instructions to troubleshoot ?

Comment: The change in the answer is definitely correct. It makes no sense to specify 0.0.0.0 as an outgoing IP address. The DNS name should be the container name for docker bridge mode. Which xray lib are you using and how are you instrumenting your code?

Comment: Thanks @MartinLöper for jumping in.
I updated my question with code excerpts, which is based on the AWS sample "colorteller"

Answer (score 0):

many thanks @MartinLöper, @shariqmaws for your feedback.
Finally, after some fiddling, the problem got solved. Most probably there was an error with the initial version of the image.
I decided to increase the loglevel of the xray-daemon within the code to "debug". After recreating the docker image, pushing it to the registry and redeploying the ECS service I suddenly received only positive log messages.....and also the XRay console showed my service....hoooray.

To confirm, the following environment setting to talk to the xray-daemon is correct and works:

```
  "environment": [
    {
      "name": "AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS",
      "value": "xray-daemon:2000"
    },
```